# I wrote this code for file handling in php,i have created href links,, but i want to pass the value of $i to the next page(rey.php))

Tags: php

```
$myfile = fopen("Cadence_html.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$i = 0;
while(!feof($myfile))  {    
    $a=fgets($myfile);

    if(   (strpos($a, 'User') === false) 
       && (strpos($a, '***') === false) 
       && (strpos($a, '!!!') === false) 
       && (strpos($a, 'RESERVATION') === false) ) {

        $i = $i + 1;
        echo '<a href="rey.php">**Kill**_____</a>';
    }
    if(strpos($a, '!!!') !== false) {
        echo '<br>';
    } else {
        echo $a.'<br>';
    }
}
fclose($myfile);`
```

Here $i is incremented for every iteration,, so `**Kill**` link is formed in loop.
I need to pass the value of $i for respective `**Kill**` link.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure exactly if this is what you mean?

```
                    $i++;
                    echo'<a href="rey.php?i='.$i.'">**Kill**_____</a>';
                    }
```

Comment: Thank You,, What you have suggested changes the url of the hyperlink,, I want like, the link should be same i.e, rey.php,, and send the value of $i as arguement

Comment: Thank You,, What you have suggested changes the URL of the hyperlink,, I want like, the link should be same i.e, rey.php,, and send the value of $i as argument. Son that i can use that value for further application.